# next button shows this error {"Conversion from string ""Error"" to type 'Integer' is not valid."}

Tags: vb.net

```vb
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Module Module1
    Public Con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Zmare\Desktop\Database\Unique Center Quetta\Unique Center Quetta\bin\Debug\DB.mdb")

    Public cmd As OleDbCommand
    Public dad As OleDbDataAdapter
    Public dst As New DataSet
    Public currentrow

End Module
 Private Sub showdata(ByVal currentrow)

        Try

            txtID.Text = dst.Tables("Invoice").Rows(currentrow)("ID")
            txtInvoiceNo.Text = dst.Tables("Invoice").Rows(currentrow)("Invoiceno")
            txtidate.Text = dst.Tables("Invoice").Rows(currentrow)("Idate")
            txtdistributor.Text = dst.Tables("Invoice").Rows(currentrow)("Distributor")
            txtaddress.Text = dst.Tables("Invoice").Rows(currentrow)("Address")
            txtstregno.Text = dst.Tables("Invoice").Rows(currentrow)("Stregno")
            txtcname.Text = dst.Tables("Invoice").Rows(currentrow)("Cname")
            txtddate.Text = dst.Tables("Invoice").Rows(currentrow)("Ddate")
            txtcaddress.Text = dst.Tables("Invoice").Rows(currentrow)("caddress")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, "Error")
        End Try
    End Sub

  Private Sub btnnext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnnext.Click
        If currentrow = dst.Tables("Invoice").Rows.Count - 1 Then
            MsgBox("You are on Last Record", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        Else
            CurrentRow += 1
            ShowData(CurrentRow)
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: The second parameter of `MsgBox()` is the `MsgBoxStyle` enumerator. You're probably mixing `MsgBox()` with `MessageBox.Show()` (where the second parameter can be the dialog's Caption).

Comment: i replaced MsgBox(ex.Message, "Error") to MsgBox("record Error") when I click next button it shows the error message but it does goto next record and when I press ok button of the msg box it works fine on other records

Comment: i left exception blank and it works fine now. thnx jimi

Comment: You should have been using `MessageBox.Show` in the first place. `MsgBox` is a VB6 holdover, like `InputBox`, `Mid` and `Len`. If you're using VB.NET, use it.

Comment: Probably the most commented suggestion in SO; turn both `Option Strict` and `Option Expliict` on. It'll show up many syntax issues, such as your un-typed `CurrentRow` variable. And maybe you've posted partial code, but you don't use `cmd` or `dad` anywhere. And watch your casing; VB isn't case-sensitive, but C# is. And you should try to be consistent in any case (excuse the pun).